# Ipv6 app rejected xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, ipv6

my app was rejected by apple with this message:

> ..We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and
>   iPhone running iOS 10.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
>
> Specifically, no action occurred when we attempted to create an
>   account..

this is what i do in my registration page:

```
if (!EQiOS.Reachability.Reachability.IsHostReachable(myurl)) 
                {
                    UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView()
                    {
                        Title = "Oops!",
                        Message = "Purtroppo sembra che non ci sia connessione, attiva la rete, se il problema persiste non esitare a contattarci!"
                    };
                    alert.AddButton("OK");
                    alert.Show();

                }
```

first of all i'm checking if there is connection and then :

i'm using this to update the user on my db

```
string check = msql.updateData(url);
```

it connects to a php page

this is the method

```
#region UPDATE_DATA
        public string updateData(string url) {


            var request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

            request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

            var response = request.GetResponse();

            System.IO.StreamReader str = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            return str.ReadToEnd();
        }
        #endregion
```

and this is for reading data on my server :

```
public List<List<string>> GetTable(string url, string nome_array, List<string> array_col)
        {

            string elemento_name = nome_array;

            int fine = array_col.Count;
            Console.WriteLine(fine);


            var multiDimensionalArr = new List<List<string>>(); // CREO LISTA MULTIDIMENSIONALE DI TIPO STRINGA CHE CONTERRA' LA TABELLA RISULTANTE


            WebClient client = new WebClient(); // INIZIALIZZO CLIENT WEB

            string value = client.DownloadString(url); //JSON IN STRINGA VALUE

            Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(value); //DESERIALIZZO JSON


            int i = 0; //VARIABILI PER IL CONTEGGIO ELEMENTI
            int j = 0; //VARIABILI PER IL CONTEGGIO ELEMENTI

            foreach (var item in jObject[elemento_name])  //PER OGNI ELEMENTO ESISTENTE NELL'ARRAY
            {
                multiDimensionalArr.Add(new List<string>()); //CREO NUOVA RIGA NELL'ARRAY

                do
                {
                    multiDimensionalArr[i].Add(Convert.ToString(jObject[elemento_name][i][array_col[j]])); // AGGIORNO ARRAY CON ELEMENTO CORRISPONDENDE
                    j++;
                } while (j < fine);


                j = 0;
                i++;
            }

            return multiDimensionalArr;

        }
```

where is the problem? 
i think that it should be because sometimes my app crashes with **ReadDone2 Failure** but i don't know if this is the problem..
and if not apple will reject my app for that?

Comment: That rejection message indicates that Apple had a problem with your app (as described).  It may or may not be due to the use of IPv6, they are merely indicating that they tested it on an IPv6 only network.  You should test your app using a pure IPv6 network and also on a different Internet connection, such as a cellular connection, to determine what network issue is causing the rejection.  What action do you take in the `else` clause of the reachability check that you have shown? Do you provide an error to the user and an option to retry?

Comment: "sometimes my app crashes with ReadDone2 Failure". If you submit an app to the App Store knowing it contains crashes then that is asking for trouble. especially if they can occur during initial login/account setup. You need to make the app rock solid especially in terms of network connections failures etc. In this particular case have you need to read the IPv6 guidelines, Apple give instructions on how you can test your app for iPV6 conformance, its quick and easy to do.